# Django file upload with Bill Id

Tags: django, database, file-upload

I'm new to Django and i'm working on uploading files.
when uploading my files, the saving is working perfectly.
but problem is i need to associate every aploaded file to a bill id, cause the uploaded file for me is a bill. 
something like

> billX_[45]

45 is the bill id in my database.
billX is the uploaded file name.

in some documentations i found that upload_to helps fo do so, but i still feel confused.

my form.py is :

```
class bills(forms.Form):
 numfacture=forms.CharField()
 myfile=forms.FileField()
```

model.py

```
class facture_ventes(models.Model):
  numfac=models.CharField(max_length=20)
  piece_joint=models.FileField(upload_to = 'FacturesVentes')
```

in my view :

```
if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['myfile']:
        myfile = request.FILES['myfile']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
        uploaded_file_url = fs.url(filename)
        return redirect('/veentes', {
            'uploaded_file_url': uploaded_file_url
        })
```

The `FacturesVentes` is added to `MEDIA_ROOT` in the settings
Any help please , Thank You So Much

Comment: `ext = str(myfile.name).split(".")[1]` 
===
`name = "billX_[45]."+ext`                                 
===
`filename = fs.save(name, myfile)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at `ModelForm`?

Instead of:

```
class bills(forms.Form):
    numfacture=forms.CharField()
    myfile=forms.FileField()
```

You can use:

```
class bills(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = facture_ventes
        fields = '__all__'
```

What this does is to present you a specific form for the model associated, in this case `facture_ventes`. When you submit this form, it will create a model with your information (numfacture and file). Also, you don't need to use `FileSystemStorage` because saving the modelform will automatically upload your file to the folder specified in `upload_to` attribute. `upload_to` attribute is a relative path from `MEDIA_URL` path defined in settings. All your files uploaded will be there.

If you want to learn more (which I strongly recommend), take a look to this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/.

Now, if you want to take a name from file namefor your numfacture field you can do something like this:

```
billform = bills(request.POST, request.FILES)

if billform.is_valid():
    bill = billform.save(commit=False)
    filename = bill.piece_joint.name.split(".")[0]
    # you build filename as you want
    bill.numfac = filename
    bill.save()
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The `upload_to` attribute can also accept a [callable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) which you can use to append the bill id to the filename.

```
def bill_filename(instance, filename):
    return '{}_{}'.format(filename, instance.numfac)


class facture_ventes(models.Model):
    numfac=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    piece_joint=models.FileField(upload_to=bill_filename)
```

Comment: i tryed to do it. but still the file is saved without the id. i've seen the documentations too and followed it. and added bill_filename to the my models.py as mentionned